# HTML Symbols not loading dynamically in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am working with some Angular and firebase code in which I am requesting some data from firebase and displaying them, simple stuff, but...

I had an array of string which contains some data like so,

```json
[
"Refraction"
"&#x6298;&#x5149;"
]
```

the second one is HTML symbols and when I tried to render it to screen using angular **interpolation**

this happened

```html
<p _ngcontent-rnr-c24>&#x6298;&#x5149;</p>
```

and when I manually hard code this to HTML file this is what I get

```html
<p _ngcontent-rnr-c24>折光</p>
```

which is what I wanted...

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an HTML Symbol you might just be better off doing it like this:

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let symbols of symbols">
   <p [innerHTML]="symbol"></p>
 </ng-container>
```

[image: Result]